# Usage of integration representation

Tags: analysis, special-functions

There are various "Integral Representations" for various functions, such as Bessel Functions.

http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.9

How is this integral regpresentation used?

In numerical calculation? or In analysis of function behavior

Comment: Usually it's used to identify when your function is a Bessel function. Also you can study asymptotics of Bessel functions for extreme parameters by doing saddle point methods. Also,, when doing asymptotics on integrals, you'll sometimes see a leading order term that's exactly a Bessel contour integral, so to first order your integral will roughly be a Bessel function.

Comment: @AlexR. Thank you very much for your comments.

Comment: "In numerical calculation?" - sometimes, yes. As an example, one of the integral representations for the Bessel function of the first kind lends itself to a very useful method for numerical evaluation using the trapezoidal rule.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. Thank you very much.